# Create a table in Jupyter Notebook that connects to a database in Beekeeper and AWS

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to generate some tables in a database that I have already created in AWS and connected through Beekeeper. I am using Jupyter notebook with Python 3 to accomplish this.

However, when I run the cell for my first table (which is after my sell where I connect to the database using psycopg2) I get a Syntax Error. Here is the code I have been trying:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
tabID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
tabName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Breed VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
Gender VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
Weight SMALLINT NOT NULL,
Age NUMERIC(2,1) NOT NULL
);

conn.commit()
```

The error is showing up with the ^ (carat) under the T in first table. I've tried moving around commas and parenthesis.

```
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10756\4115600721.py", line 1
    CREATE TABLE table(
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out, and I'm posting the answer for anyone who might run into something similar.

```
table = ("""CREATE TABLE table (
tabID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
tabName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Breed VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
Gender VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
Weight SMALLINT NOT NULL,
Age NUMERIC(2,1) NOT NULL);
""")
cursor.execute(table)
conn.commit()
```